# Need to send information from chrome to external app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, batch-file

I have an app (software in my windows) which I can do whatherver I want with it and I need this app to be notified when some JS code is run inside chrome. Ok this is not easy.

So I came up with this idea: when I want to notify my app (running on my windows) to do something, I just downloaded a cacheable file (using js) to my chrome browser. THEN my app can check every 10 seconds the "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache" directory to know if a file with a specific size was created.

This is working flawlessly! But I wonder if you guys would recommend any other method to send a command or anything from JS code running inside chrome to an external app running in windows?

Comment: Using the file method is fine. But alternatively, you could have your Windows app register a custom protocol. For example, Github Desktop uses `x-github-client://`.

Comment: Can I request, using JS, to my browser register a custom protocol?

Comment: i TRIED navigator.registerProtocolHandler(
    'web+mystuff', 'http://example.com/rph?q=%s', 'My App');
 BUT IT REQUESTS the user to press ALLOW. It's not a good idea in that view of point.

Comment: As you've seen, browsers place restrictions on how JavaScript registers custom protocols. But I believe native applications (including Electron based apps) can register protocols whenever they'd like.